# moving average and errors - Matlab

Tags: matlab, average

I have a series of data x,y and I am trying to find the moving average. The x data numbers are integers from 1 to 100 while the y data are numbers from 0.01 to 1 and they also have a standard deviation y_dev (which we derive because the experiment is repeated several times).
I am trying to find the moving average using the 20 closest neighbors (using Matlab):

```
 num_data=length(x)
 mov_average=y
 for i=11,num_data-10 % we leave the data in the edges the same
 ind1(i)=i-10
 ind2(i)=i+10
 mov_average(i)=mean(y(ind1(i):ind2(i)));
 end
```

The above way derives the moving average but I do not know how to use the standard deviation that I have for each y data point because some data points have much larger standard deviations than others which means they are not as reliable as others (so they probably weigh less). How can i include the standard deviation for each data point in the above calculation?

Thank you.

Comment: Moving _average_ or moving _median_? Regarding the question "How can i include the standard deviation for each data point in the above calculation", it depends on what you want to do. You should first decide that (which is not a programming question). A suggestion: can't you use the whole set of data for each `x` (instead of just the average and standard deviation) and compute mean/median from that?

Comment: @LuisMendo I wanted to do moving average (i edited the code to reflect that). The data set is a time series experiment and it has been repeated several times (which is how i have standard deviations for each point). I want to use the standard deviation for each point in my calculation of moving average because I want the points with smaller standard deviation to weigh more than the points with larger standard deviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a vector `a`. Then another way of writing `mean(a)` as a weighted average is `a*wts'`, where `wts = ones(1,numel(a))/numel(a)`. In your case, you have `a = y(ind1(i):ind2(i))`.

It sounds like what you're wanting to use is a weighted moving average, where your weights `wts` are no longer identical, but are chosen using the standard deviation of the corresponding values.

Assuming the vector `sd` holds the standard deviations, here's one way of doing this:

```
num_data=length(x)
mov_average=y
for i=11,num_data-10
   ind1(i)=i-10
   ind2(i)=i+10
   sds = 1./sd(ind1(i):ind2(i)); % smaller sd -> larger weight
   wts = sds./sum(sds); % weights should sum to 1
   mov_average(i) = y*wts';
end
```

Here, the values with smaller standard deviations will contribute larger weights.

An alternative idea is to calculate the simple moving average of both `y` and your standard deviations `sd`, and then plot them alongside one another.

```
wts = ones(1,10)/10;
y_mean = conv(y, wts, 'valid'); % moving avg of y
y_lb = y + conv(sd, wts, 'valid'); % moving avg of lower bound on y
y_ub = y - conv(sd, wts, 'valid'); % moving avg of upper bound on y
```

This has the advantage of being more statistically interpretable than choosing weights as a function of the standard deviations.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for! It works really well for my data.